I have distributed my Certificate Authority's RootCA, but my certificate signing request is failing when trying to issue to my devices
This is a small project but very important, the short version is this:
I have 4 devices, 3 servers and 1 Workstation in Azure

Subnet1
PDC
Certificate Server

Subnet2
File Server

Subnet3
Workstation


All devices other than the certificate server are on the domain sandbox.local
All can communicate and ping, but I cannot get encryption to work via certificate authority.
It comes up with the following error: "A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider".
Can anyone help me make sense of this?

The simplest way forward is to sign your certificate for sandbox.local with a CA that is automatically trusted. Let's Encrypt is not really an option with a domain like sandbox.local. You have not really provided enough information to do any additional diagnostic. However, "a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider", only happens when the Root CA is not signed by a trusted provider (i.e. it's self-signed).

Firstly thank you for your response. Apologies for the lack of information, as I wasn't sure what to provide. I must use this server to self-sign, as its part of the criteria for the project. I have created and distributed the RootCA.csr to each device, but when creating the .req file on each device, it comes up as .file instead and comes with this same error every time I export them to the CA and try to issue them. Let me know if you need more information.

You moved the root CA into the system's certificate store and mark it as a certificate the system should trust.

I moved the RootCA into the workstations "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" on local computer and this issue still persists. Are there any other checks I could perform?

You installed the entire certificate chain to the appropriate certificate stores?  This means moving the Root CA used to signed the certificate being used in the Trusted Root CA, and likewise also install the certificate(s) onto the system.

That's what I believe I did, I copied the RootCA to each device and installed them to the TRCA section, everything seems fine until I try to issue the .req file on the Certificate Authority

"I cannot get encryption to work via certificate authority." - What software is throwing this error exactly?

I'm trying to issue a .req file from the Workstation in the Certificate Authority console.
